# bower заворачивает папку bower_components в папку app

Tags: bower

bower заворачивает папку bower_components в папку app файла .bowerrc не в текущей, не в родительской директории нету, подскажите может кто знает в чем дело.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну так создайте .bowerrc и пропишите там необходимую конфигурацию.

bower.json, bower init.